# Generating random Sudoku via Z3 isn't random and is slow

Tags: z3

I have the following SMT code that I wrote in order to generate a random sudoku. More specifically, it generates a filled sudoku given an empty 9x9 matrix. It was the most simple example I could come up with to try it on Z3 to learn how it works.

`sudoku.smt`:

```
; 9x9 cells 1 to 9
(declare-const cell_1_1 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_1_1))(assert (<= cell_1_1 9))
(declare-const cell_1_2 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_1_2))(assert (<= cell_1_2 9))
(declare-const cell_1_3 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_1_3))(assert (<= cell_1_3 9))
(declare-const cell_1_4 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_1_4))(assert (<= cell_1_4 9))
(declare-const cell_1_5 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_1_5))(assert (<= cell_1_5 9))
(declare-const cell_1_6 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_1_6))(assert (<= cell_1_6 9))
(declare-const cell_1_7 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_1_7))(assert (<= cell_1_7 9))
(declare-const cell_1_8 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_1_8))(assert (<= cell_1_8 9))
(declare-const cell_1_9 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_1_9))(assert (<= cell_1_9 9))
(declare-const cell_2_1 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_2_1))(assert (<= cell_2_1 9))
(declare-const cell_2_2 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_2_2))(assert (<= cell_2_2 9))
(declare-const cell_2_3 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_2_3))(assert (<= cell_2_3 9))
(declare-const cell_2_4 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_2_4))(assert (<= cell_2_4 9))
(declare-const cell_2_5 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_2_5))(assert (<= cell_2_5 9))
(declare-const cell_2_6 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_2_6))(assert (<= cell_2_6 9))
(declare-const cell_2_7 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_2_7))(assert (<= cell_2_7 9))
(declare-const cell_2_8 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_2_8))(assert (<= cell_2_8 9))
(declare-const cell_2_9 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_2_9))(assert (<= cell_2_9 9))
(declare-const cell_3_1 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_3_1))(assert (<= cell_3_1 9))
(declare-const cell_3_2 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_3_2))(assert (<= cell_3_2 9))
(declare-const cell_3_3 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_3_3))(assert (<= cell_3_3 9))
(declare-const cell_3_4 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_3_4))(assert (<= cell_3_4 9))
(declare-const cell_3_5 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_3_5))(assert (<= cell_3_5 9))
(declare-const cell_3_6 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_3_6))(assert (<= cell_3_6 9))
(declare-const cell_3_7 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_3_7))(assert (<= cell_3_7 9))
(declare-const cell_3_8 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_3_8))(assert (<= cell_3_8 9))
(declare-const cell_3_9 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_3_9))(assert (<= cell_3_9 9))
(declare-const cell_4_1 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_4_1))(assert (<= cell_4_1 9))
(declare-const cell_4_2 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_4_2))(assert (<= cell_4_2 9))
(declare-const cell_4_3 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_4_3))(assert (<= cell_4_3 9))
(declare-const cell_4_4 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_4_4))(assert (<= cell_4_4 9))
(declare-const cell_4_5 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_4_5))(assert (<= cell_4_5 9))
(declare-const cell_4_6 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_4_6))(assert (<= cell_4_6 9))
(declare-const cell_4_7 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_4_7))(assert (<= cell_4_7 9))
(declare-const cell_4_8 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_4_8))(assert (<= cell_4_8 9))
(declare-const cell_4_9 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_4_9))(assert (<= cell_4_9 9))
(declare-const cell_5_1 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_5_1))(assert (<= cell_5_1 9))
(declare-const cell_5_2 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_5_2))(assert (<= cell_5_2 9))
(declare-const cell_5_3 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_5_3))(assert (<= cell_5_3 9))
(declare-const cell_5_4 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_5_4))(assert (<= cell_5_4 9))
(declare-const cell_5_5 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_5_5))(assert (<= cell_5_5 9))
(declare-const cell_5_6 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_5_6))(assert (<= cell_5_6 9))
(declare-const cell_5_7 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_5_7))(assert (<= cell_5_7 9))
(declare-const cell_5_8 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_5_8))(assert (<= cell_5_8 9))
(declare-const cell_5_9 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_5_9))(assert (<= cell_5_9 9))
(declare-const cell_6_1 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_6_1))(assert (<= cell_6_1 9))
(declare-const cell_6_2 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_6_2))(assert (<= cell_6_2 9))
(declare-const cell_6_3 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_6_3))(assert (<= cell_6_3 9))
(declare-const cell_6_4 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_6_4))(assert (<= cell_6_4 9))
(declare-const cell_6_5 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_6_5))(assert (<= cell_6_5 9))
(declare-const cell_6_6 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_6_6))(assert (<= cell_6_6 9))
(declare-const cell_6_7 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_6_7))(assert (<= cell_6_7 9))
(declare-const cell_6_8 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_6_8))(assert (<= cell_6_8 9))
(declare-const cell_6_9 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_6_9))(assert (<= cell_6_9 9))
(declare-const cell_7_1 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_7_1))(assert (<= cell_7_1 9))
(declare-const cell_7_2 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_7_2))(assert (<= cell_7_2 9))
(declare-const cell_7_3 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_7_3))(assert (<= cell_7_3 9))
(declare-const cell_7_4 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_7_4))(assert (<= cell_7_4 9))
(declare-const cell_7_5 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_7_5))(assert (<= cell_7_5 9))
(declare-const cell_7_6 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_7_6))(assert (<= cell_7_6 9))
(declare-const cell_7_7 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_7_7))(assert (<= cell_7_7 9))
(declare-const cell_7_8 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_7_8))(assert (<= cell_7_8 9))
(declare-const cell_7_9 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_7_9))(assert (<= cell_7_9 9))
(declare-const cell_8_1 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_8_1))(assert (<= cell_8_1 9))
(declare-const cell_8_2 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_8_2))(assert (<= cell_8_2 9))
(declare-const cell_8_3 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_8_3))(assert (<= cell_8_3 9))
(declare-const cell_8_4 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_8_4))(assert (<= cell_8_4 9))
(declare-const cell_8_5 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_8_5))(assert (<= cell_8_5 9))
(declare-const cell_8_6 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_8_6))(assert (<= cell_8_6 9))
(declare-const cell_8_7 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_8_7))(assert (<= cell_8_7 9))
(declare-const cell_8_8 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_8_8))(assert (<= cell_8_8 9))
(declare-const cell_8_9 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_8_9))(assert (<= cell_8_9 9))
(declare-const cell_9_1 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_9_1))(assert (<= cell_9_1 9))
(declare-const cell_9_2 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_9_2))(assert (<= cell_9_2 9))
(declare-const cell_9_3 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_9_3))(assert (<= cell_9_3 9))
(declare-const cell_9_4 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_9_4))(assert (<= cell_9_4 9))
(declare-const cell_9_5 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_9_5))(assert (<= cell_9_5 9))
(declare-const cell_9_6 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_9_6))(assert (<= cell_9_6 9))
(declare-const cell_9_7 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_9_7))(assert (<= cell_9_7 9))
(declare-const cell_9_8 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_9_8))(assert (<= cell_9_8 9))
(declare-const cell_9_9 Int)(assert (<= 1 cell_9_9))(assert (<= cell_9_9 9))

; distinct values in rows
(assert (distinct cell_1_1 cell_1_2 cell_1_3 cell_1_4 cell_1_5 cell_1_6 cell_1_7 cell_1_8 cell_1_9))
(assert (distinct cell_2_1 cell_2_2 cell_2_3 cell_2_4 cell_2_5 cell_2_6 cell_2_7 cell_2_8 cell_2_9))
(assert (distinct cell_3_1 cell_3_2 cell_3_3 cell_3_4 cell_3_5 cell_3_6 cell_3_7 cell_3_8 cell_3_9))
(assert (distinct cell_4_1 cell_4_2 cell_4_3 cell_4_4 cell_4_5 cell_4_6 cell_4_7 cell_4_8 cell_4_9))
(assert (distinct cell_5_1 cell_5_2 cell_5_3 cell_5_4 cell_5_5 cell_5_6 cell_5_7 cell_5_8 cell_5_9))
(assert (distinct cell_6_1 cell_6_2 cell_6_3 cell_6_4 cell_6_5 cell_6_6 cell_6_7 cell_6_8 cell_6_9))
(assert (distinct cell_7_1 cell_7_2 cell_7_3 cell_7_4 cell_7_5 cell_7_6 cell_7_7 cell_7_8 cell_7_9))
(assert (distinct cell_8_1 cell_8_2 cell_8_3 cell_8_4 cell_8_5 cell_8_6 cell_8_7 cell_8_8 cell_8_9))
(assert (distinct cell_9_1 cell_9_2 cell_9_3 cell_9_4 cell_9_5 cell_9_6 cell_9_7 cell_9_8 cell_9_9))

; distinct values in cells
(assert (distinct cell_1_1 cell_2_1 cell_3_1 cell_4_1 cell_5_1 cell_6_1 cell_7_1 cell_8_1 cell_9_1))
(assert (distinct cell_1_2 cell_2_2 cell_3_2 cell_4_2 cell_5_2 cell_6_2 cell_7_2 cell_8_2 cell_9_2))
(assert (distinct cell_1_3 cell_2_3 cell_3_3 cell_4_3 cell_5_3 cell_6_3 cell_7_3 cell_8_3 cell_9_3))
(assert (distinct cell_1_4 cell_2_4 cell_3_4 cell_4_4 cell_5_4 cell_6_4 cell_7_4 cell_8_4 cell_9_4))
(assert (distinct cell_1_5 cell_2_5 cell_3_5 cell_4_5 cell_5_5 cell_6_5 cell_7_5 cell_8_5 cell_9_5))
(assert (distinct cell_1_6 cell_2_6 cell_3_6 cell_4_6 cell_5_6 cell_6_6 cell_7_6 cell_8_6 cell_9_6))
(assert (distinct cell_1_7 cell_2_7 cell_3_7 cell_4_7 cell_5_7 cell_6_7 cell_7_7 cell_8_7 cell_9_7))
(assert (distinct cell_1_8 cell_2_8 cell_3_8 cell_4_8 cell_5_8 cell_6_8 cell_7_8 cell_8_8 cell_9_8))
(assert (distinct cell_1_9 cell_2_9 cell_3_9 cell_4_9 cell_5_9 cell_6_9 cell_7_9 cell_8_9 cell_9_9))

; distinct values in squares
(assert (distinct cell_1_1 cell_1_2 cell_1_3 cell_2_1 cell_2_2 cell_2_3 cell_3_1 cell_3_2 cell_3_3))
(assert (distinct cell_1_4 cell_1_5 cell_1_6 cell_2_4 cell_2_5 cell_2_6 cell_3_4 cell_3_5 cell_3_6))
(assert (distinct cell_1_7 cell_1_8 cell_1_9 cell_2_7 cell_2_8 cell_2_9 cell_3_7 cell_3_8 cell_3_9))
(assert (distinct cell_4_1 cell_4_2 cell_4_3 cell_5_1 cell_5_2 cell_5_3 cell_6_1 cell_6_2 cell_6_3))
(assert (distinct cell_4_4 cell_4_5 cell_4_6 cell_5_4 cell_5_5 cell_5_6 cell_6_4 cell_6_5 cell_6_6))
(assert (distinct cell_4_7 cell_4_8 cell_4_9 cell_5_7 cell_5_8 cell_5_9 cell_6_7 cell_6_8 cell_6_9))
(assert (distinct cell_7_1 cell_7_2 cell_7_3 cell_8_1 cell_8_2 cell_8_3 cell_9_1 cell_9_2 cell_9_3))
(assert (distinct cell_7_4 cell_7_5 cell_7_6 cell_8_4 cell_8_5 cell_8_6 cell_9_4 cell_9_5 cell_9_6))
(assert (distinct cell_7_7 cell_7_8 cell_7_9 cell_8_7 cell_8_8 cell_8_9 cell_9_7 cell_9_8 cell_9_9))

; generate one for me, please
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

I execute it via:

```
z3 sudoku.smt
```

And as a result, I get a generated sudoku:

```
(model
  (define-fun cell_2_9 () Int
    8)
  (define-fun cell_3_9 () Int
    9)
  (define-fun cell_7_6 () Int
    7)
  (define-fun cell_7_7 () Int
    1)
  (define-fun cell_7_4 () Int
    5)
  (define-fun cell_5_3 () Int
    1)
  (define-fun cell_3_7 () Int
    2)
  (define-fun cell_9_7 () Int
    9)
  (define-fun cell_1_8 () Int
    3)
  (define-fun cell_4_4 () Int
    8)
  (define-fun cell_9_4 () Int
    1)
  (define-fun cell_2_1 () Int
    9)
  (define-fun cell_2_2 () Int
    1)
  (define-fun cell_4_1 () Int
    6)
  (define-fun cell_5_5 () Int
    3)
  (define-fun cell_1_2 () Int
    6)
  (define-fun cell_3_5 () Int
    1)
  (define-fun cell_1_3 () Int
    4)
  (define-fun cell_1_4 () Int
    7)
  (define-fun cell_9_8 () Int
    7)
  (define-fun cell_8_8 () Int
    8)
  (define-fun cell_3_3 () Int
    5)
  (define-fun cell_2_3 () Int
    2)
  (define-fun cell_6_8 () Int
    9)
  (define-fun cell_7_3 () Int
    6)
  (define-fun cell_9_1 () Int
    2)
  (define-fun cell_5_7 () Int
    8)
  (define-fun cell_5_9 () Int
    4)
  (define-fun cell_3_4 () Int
    6)
  (define-fun cell_6_7 () Int
    6)
  (define-fun cell_2_5 () Int
    5)
  (define-fun cell_6_2 () Int
    3)
  (define-fun cell_8_2 () Int
    9)
  (define-fun cell_6_4 () Int
    2)
  (define-fun cell_2_4 () Int
    4)
  (define-fun cell_2_7 () Int
    7)
  (define-fun cell_4_5 () Int
    7)
  (define-fun cell_3_2 () Int
    7)
  (define-fun cell_4_9 () Int
    2)
  (define-fun cell_9_2 () Int
    5)
  (define-fun cell_6_9 () Int
    7)
  (define-fun cell_1_9 () Int
    1)
  (define-fun cell_7_5 () Int
    9)
  (define-fun cell_9_5 () Int
    8)
  (define-fun cell_9_3 () Int
    3)
  (define-fun cell_8_7 () Int
    4)
  (define-fun cell_5_1 () Int
    7)
  (define-fun cell_4_7 () Int
    3)
  (define-fun cell_3_8 () Int
    4)
  (define-fun cell_9_9 () Int
    6)
  (define-fun cell_8_1 () Int
    1)
  (define-fun cell_4_2 () Int
    4)
  (define-fun cell_4_3 () Int
    9)
  (define-fun cell_7_2 () Int
    8)
  (define-fun cell_8_9 () Int
    5)
  (define-fun cell_1_5 () Int
    2)
  (define-fun cell_1_1 () Int
    8)
  (define-fun cell_2_6 () Int
    3)
  (define-fun cell_6_6 () Int
    1)
  (define-fun cell_5_8 () Int
    5)
  (define-fun cell_5_4 () Int
    9)
  (define-fun cell_9_6 () Int
    4)
  (define-fun cell_6_1 () Int
    5)
  (define-fun cell_3_6 () Int
    8)
  (define-fun cell_6_3 () Int
    8)
  (define-fun cell_8_6 () Int
    2)
  (define-fun cell_7_9 () Int
    3)
  (define-fun cell_5_2 () Int
    2)
  (define-fun cell_4_6 () Int
    5)
  (define-fun cell_7_1 () Int
    4)
  (define-fun cell_8_4 () Int
    3)
  (define-fun cell_4_8 () Int
    1)
  (define-fun cell_1_7 () Int
    5)
  (define-fun cell_6_5 () Int
    4)
  (define-fun cell_7_8 () Int
    2)
  (define-fun cell_1_6 () Int
    9)
  (define-fun cell_2_8 () Int
    6)
  (define-fun cell_8_3 () Int
    7)
  (define-fun cell_3_1 () Int
    3)
  (define-fun cell_8_5 () Int
    6)
  (define-fun cell_5_6 () Int
    6)
)
```

However, I have two issues with this:

1. It takes quite a long time to finish, about 25 seconds on my machine.
2. It generates the same sudoku every time I run it.

This makes me wonder that I'm doing something wrong. What I'd expect is a very fast result that's different every time. How can I achieve that?

To be honest, I'm struggling a bit with the documentation resources regarding Z3. I'm trying to follow https://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/guide, but everything is explained very briefly, and I cannot find any detailed manual. So any resources/recommendations/links are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you expect a different result every time? SMT/SAT solvers only give you a solution, not necessarily a random one.

Comment: @PiRocks I assumed that there's some non-determinism involved in there, but I'm apparently wrong. Maybe it's possible to make it decide more randomly somehow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Int` is a bad domain to choose for this problem. Instead, use a bit-vector instead. That is, replace your declarations with:

```
(declare-const cell_1_1 (_ BitVec 4))
(assert (bvule #x1 cell_1_1))
(assert (bvule cell_1_1 #x9))
```

Once you make this change for all the variables, you'll see that z3 solves the problem much more quickly. (In my test, almost instantly.)

Regarding randomness: You can play around with random-seed settings, but it's unlikely an SMT solver will generate different solutions for you; they are tuned for solving constraints, not exploring the possible search space in any meaningful way (random or otherwise.) A practical solution would be to randomly generate a few of the cell values (using some other program) and hard-code them: That is, assert that `cell_3_4` is `5`, and some other cell is `9` etc. So long as you assert a few of these randomly (~10 or so), you should get good sudoku instances. (Unless it becomes `unsat` of course.)

Comment: To add to the randomness comment. You could attempt to enumerate all possible solutions by iteratively getting a solution and then adding an assertion that the solution is not a solution.

Comment: Indeed. Unfortunately, this isn't very practical. (1) It's hard to use SMT-Lib directly to say "give me a different model." To overcome this issue, you can use a higher-level interface from a programming language like C/Java/Haskell/Python. (2) The sheer number of possible sudoku boards make generation of "interesting" ones difficult. How do you even define "interesting" in this context? Perhaps no "large sequences?"  Something to ponder!

Comment: Very interesting performance optimisation, @alias. Could you please explain why the bit-vector-based encoding is solved that much quicker?

Comment: @MalteSchwerhoff Most likely with bit-vectors, the `distinct` constraints directly translate to SAT clauses with no arithmetic involved. The use of `Int` will give rise to a lot of arithmetic that the solver will have to negotiate between the theory-solver and the SAT engine. Also, the search space is significantly smaller. Add on top of that the bit-vector engines are really fine-tuned in z3, I'm not surprised z3 goes through it much faster than the encoding with unbounded ints.

Answer (score 0):

After studying z3 tactics a bit more, I came up with a possibly better solution than the answer from @alias (thank you for the answer anyway, it lead me in the right direction).

### Performance

Instead of using `(check-sat)` in my code, it's possible to use `(check-sat-using ...)` and further specify tactics to be applied.

The default tactic is `smt` which is slow in my case. After studying the help from `(help-tactics)`, I found out there's a tactic `nla2bv` that can be used.

Quoting from the `(help-tactics)`:

> nla2bv converts a nonlinear arithmetic problem into a bit-vector problem, in most cases, the resultant goal is an under approximation and is useful for finding models.

In code, this means:

```
(check-sat-using (then nla2bv smt))
```

### Randomness

Regarding randomness, it's possible to provide a random seed to the `smt` tactic via the `:random-seed` parameter. If I provide different seed, I get a different output model.

In code, this looks like:

```
(check-sat-using (then nla2bv (using-params smt :random-seed 999)))
```

Although, as @alias pointed out in the answer, this gives only very limited options to control the output.

---

After these changes, I'm able to get from ~25 seconds to less than 1 second. For more performance gain, I'm sure it's possible to tweak the used tactics even more.

Comment: Not only this is not portable (i.e., won't work with Yices, MathSat, etc.), I wouldn't even count on it working with z3 with future releases. Tactics change behavior without much documentation, and they're very fickle to use. For serious work, I'd recommend sticking to bit-vectors, which should perform well with all SMT solvers out there.

Comment: @alias Good to know, thanks for the heads up and for your help on this.